# Magento Disable Filter Field to Admin Grid

Tags: magento

I have a custom module with a backend page. In the grid, I show the customer email as the user name. By default, Magento adds a filter to every column in the grid. Now, when I try to filter by the customer's email, I get an exception saying that my custom table doesn't have an email column. Magento is trying to find that in my custom table. How can I fix this problem, or how can I remove the field of that column so that the admin can't filter by that field.
Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Add the option

```
    'filter' => false
```

to the column you want to remove the filter from in the grid view (e.g. app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php)

```
    $this->addColumn('email', array(
       'header'    => Mage::helper('module')->__('Email'),
       'align'     =>'left',
       'index'     => 'email',
       'filter' => false,
   ));
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you meant "how can I remove the field of that column so that the admin can ' **t** filter by that field"

If so, I can tell you how to remove the email field.

Open /app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminthml/Module/Grid.php

Somewhere in the protected function _prepareColumns() you should find something like :

```
  $this->addColumn('email', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('module')->__('Email'),
      'align'     =>'left',
      'index'     => 'email',
  ));
```

Just comment this lines.

And watch out that, in the __construct method at the very beginning of the whole class, you don't have

```
  $this->setDefaultSort('email');
```

If so, change it to

```
$this->setDefaultSort('id'); // if you have an id field in your module.
```

Comment: ok, i want to show the column, but remove the field in the top of the column, how can i do that?

Comment: if i do that, i remove the column, i don't want to remove the column, just the field in the top of it, that is used to filter

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an email column in your custom table, then I assume you're creating your grid by joining your custom table to a core table that contains the users email address, such as `customer_entity`.

When you filter on a column, Magento uses the column index to produce the where clause. Which in your case will give something like `WHERE email LIKE '%filter value%'`, but it wont find email in your custom table.

You might be able to fix this by using `filter_index` to explicitly tell Magento which table and column to use when building the where clause. Try something like this

```
$this->addColumn('email', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('module')->__('Email'),
    'index'     => 'email',
    'filter_index'          => 'core_table.email',
));
```

where `core_table` is the table you are joining with.